# Resizing a freetext annotation in pdfnet converts specials characters into unicode (PdfNet)

Tags: annotations, freetext, pdftron, pdfnet

I'm using the toolmode e_annot_edit to resize my freetext annotations. But when i make the annotation smaller/bigger, some characters like 'é' convert into '\U00E9. Is there any way to fix this? I googled and looked in the forum but could not find any information on this subject...

it also happens with the è,ù and ç characters

Comment: Could provide the PDFNet version number, and what platform/OS you are on, and what framework. To get version right click the DLL on windows, or at runtime call PDFNet.GetVersion. For example: 6.6.0.45000 WPF

Comment: version 5.1 winforms.

Comment: This should be fixed in the latest version. Please download the SDK from our site, or get from Nuget. https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/downloads.html